# The reputation_change field is missing from the reputation results on some CW posts

Tags: bug, reputation

When querying the [/users/{ids}/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users) API route, the `reputation_change` field is missing from the results on community-wiki answers.  I think the [reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation) type should always include this field, and its value should be 0 if there was no reputation change on the post. (Alternatively, you could just exclude 0-change reputation objects from the query results.)

Here's a query example with results that are missing the `reputation_change` field:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#page=8&pagesize=100&ids=1288&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

The CW posts [13977422](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474972/ibatis-and-sql-timestamp/13977422#13977422) and [13975947](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736199/regex-matching-for-variables-and-numbers/13975947#13975947) are the two that are missing the field.

```
{
  "on_date": 1356103151,
  "vote_type": "accepts",
  "post_type": "answer",
  "post_id": 13977422,
  "user_id": 1288
},
{
  "on_date": 1356060056,
  "vote_type": "accepts",
  "post_type": "answer",
  "post_id": 13975947,
  "user_id": 1288
}
```

The two examples above are answer accepts, but this also sometimes happens on [answer upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745189/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-sqlalchemy-objects-primary-key/8669380#8669380).

```
{
  "on_date": 1379667908,
  "vote_type": "up_votes",
  "post_type": "answer",
  "post_id": 8669380,
  "user_id": 1288
}

{
  "on_date": 1374767790,
  "vote_type": "up_votes",
  "post_type": "answer",
  "post_id": 17593979,
  "user_id": 1288
}
```

But not always. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258954/java-out-with-the-old-in-with-the-new/623007#623007) that has a `reputation_change` value of 0.

```
{
  "on_date": 1380379795,
  "reputation_change": 0,
  "vote_type": "up_votes",
  "post_type": "answer",
  "post_id": 623007,
  "user_id": 1288
}
```

From this very small sample, it looks like the `reputation_change` field is missing on posts where the community wiki checkbox was checked when the post was created.